# android: How to filter items based on child items?

Tags: java, android, filtering

This is my model:

```
public class AudioFile {
    private int id;
    private String fileName;
    private String[] subStrings;
    public AudioFile(int id, String fileName, String[] subStrings){
        this.id = id;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.subStrings = subStrings;
    }
        public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
        public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
        public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
        public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
        public String[] getSubStrings() {
        return subStrings;
    }
        public void setSubStrings(String[] subStrings) {
        this.subStrings = subStrings;
    }
        @Override
    public String toString() {
        return fileName;
    }
}
```

I populated my list view, and use my custom adapter. Now I want to filter the list view based on `subStrings` array:

```
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
    if (constraint != null) {
        suggestions.clear();
        for (AudioFile _data : itemsAll) {
            if (_data.getSubStrings().contains(constraint)) {
                suggestions.add(_data);
            }
        }
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = suggestions;
            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            return filterResults;
    } else {
            return new FilterResults();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I just filter result based on `_data.getSubStrings().equals(constraint)` But it doesn't work.
Any idea?

Comment: what is getSubStrings() ?

Comment: It contains array of Strings

Comment: Please don't change the question once people start answering it, other than to add clarification.  Changing the actual code from something that compiles but doesn't work, to something that doesn't compile, just invalidates people's answers.

Comment: @SirwanAfifi,have you given down vote to my question can you please given reason for it ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana I didn't down vote your answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace,have you given down vote to my ans ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana What difference does it make who downvoted it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
for (AudioFile _data : itemsAll) {
    String[] subStringsArray = _data.getSubStrings();
    for(String subString : subStringsArray){
        if(subString.equals(constraint)){
           suggestions.add(_data);
           break;
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`equals` is not right way to check because data types are different. You should use `Arrays.asList(_data.getSubStrings()).contains(constraint)`

Comment: If this doesn't work, then you need to express your requirement more clearly.  In what way is this solution inadequate?  Because it seems fine to me.

Comment: Your updated if statement is different from mine. You need to wrap with `Arrays.asList(...)`